# UIVisualEffectView: Enabling Vibrancy in IB Disables Blur Effect

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uivisualeffectview

I have a background `UIImageView` behind a `UIVisualEffectView`. When I enable [x]Vibrancy on the `UIVisualEffectView` in storyboard, it disables the blur effect completely.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your views according to the hierarchy bellow:
[image]

(a short tutorial on creating 
[blur on iOS8 using interface builder](http://dannyshmueli.com/blog/2015/03/07/interface-builder-and-blur-with-vibrancy/))

Comment: Vibrancy effect view should not necessarily be a subview of Blur effect view. 

[RTFM](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivibrancyeffect)